# How to get multiple selected values of MenuBar -VAADIN

Tags: vaadin

I am working on vaadin, I need the values selected from menubar and display in label. I tried one example code which I mentioned below.

```
final MenuBar menubar = new MenuBar();
layout.addComponent(menubar);

MenuBar.MenuItem beverages = menubar.addItem("Beverages", null, null);
Label selection = new Label("-");
layout.addComponent(selection);

MenuBar.Command mycommand = new MenuBar.Command() {

    public void menuSelected(MenuItem selectedItem) {
        selection.setValue("Ordered a " + selectedItem.getText() +
                           " from menu.");
    }
};
MenuBar.MenuItem hot_beverages = beverages.addItem("Hot", null, null);
hot_beverages.addItem("Tea", null, mycommand);
hot_beverages.addItem("Coffee", null, mycommand);
MenuBar.MenuItem cold_beverages =
        beverages.addItem("Cold", null, null);
cold_beverages.addItem("Milk", null, mycommand);

MenuBar.MenuItem snacks = menubar.addItem("Snacks", null, null);
snacks.addItem("Weisswurst", null, mycommand);
snacks.addItem("Salami", null, mycommand);

MenuBar.MenuItem services = menubar.addItem("Services", null, null);
services.addItem("Car Service", null, mycommand);
setContent(layout);
```

The problem is, it is displaying only one selected item.

If I select another item, the label value is replaced by recently selected item.  My requirement is to display all the menu items that are selected.

Comment: please help me out.

Comment: Vaadin MenuBar does not appear to support multiselect. try using a list select widget : https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-input/multiple-value/list-select

Comment: Thank you for your response.Yes, Multiple values working with list. But I need in MenuBar, Is there any way?

Comment: @petey fyi, don't know if you ever used them like this, but somewhat similar to multi-select lists, [**some** menu items can be _checkable_](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/MenuBar.MenuItem.html#setCheckable-boolean-). See my answer below for a sample. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a bit on what you really need to do, but for starters you have to do 2 things:

- make the items [checkable](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/MenuBar.MenuItem.html#setCheckable-boolean-) (those that are supposed to be)
- keep track of the items that were selected. For the sample below (updated from your original code) I used a list, but you could also do something like `item.getParent().getChildren()` and check which children are checked

**Code:**

```
public class MultiSelectionMenu extends VerticalLayout {
    public MultiSelectionMenu() {
        final MenuBar menubar = new MenuBar();

        MenuBar.MenuItem beverages = menubar.addItem("Beverages", null, null);
        Label selection = new Label("-");
        addComponent(selection);

        MenuBar.Command selectionHandler = new MenuBar.Command() {
            private List<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<>();

            public void menuSelected(MenuBar.MenuItem item) {
                if (item.isChecked()) {
                    selectedItems.add(item.getText());
                } else {
                    selectedItems.remove(item.getText());
                }
                selection.setValue("Ordered: " + Arrays.toString(selectedItems.toArray()));
            }
        };
        MenuBar.MenuItem hot_beverages = beverages.addItem("Hot", null, null);
        hot_beverages.addItem("Tea", null, selectionHandler).setCheckable(true);
        hot_beverages.addItem("Coffee", null, selectionHandler).setCheckable(true);
        MenuBar.MenuItem cold_beverages = beverages.addItem("Cold", null, null);
        cold_beverages.addItem("Milk", null, selectionHandler).setCheckable(true);

        MenuBar.MenuItem snacks = menubar.addItem("Snacks", null, null);
        snacks.addItem("Weisswurst", null, selectionHandler).setCheckable(true);
        snacks.addItem("Salami", null, selectionHandler).setCheckable(true);

        MenuBar.MenuItem services = menubar.addItem("Services", null, null);
        services.addItem("Car Service", null, selectionHandler).setCheckable(true);

        addComponent(menubar);
    }
}
```

**Result:**[image: multi-menu-selection]